# Invite people not on friends or recent list (without adding them)

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there any way to invite specific people to your game if they are not listed on the social tab (Friend/Recent lists)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the available commands and key bindings there doesn't seem to be a way to do this.

There are some command line switches referenced [here](http://diablo3.voltnova.com/tag/diablo-3-command-line/) that might have allowed something like that but most of them appear to have been removed from the retail version.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking to someone in one of the chat rooms in game you can right click their name, you will get a drop down list, with the option to invite to party. They can also do the same to you to send you an invite to join theirs or your game.